# ASP .NET 5 (vNext) run on IIS (run but not redirect)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-core

1. I create test project on asp.net 5 RC1.
2. Build and run on IIS Express
3. Publish by file system
4. Create new application in "Default Web Site" http://localhost/asp5
5. Enable log in wwwroot\web.config
6. Get 404 error in browser http://localhost/asp5
7. In log **Now listening on: http://localhost:29715**
8. I can open http://localhost:29715 in browser
9. In log present error

   info: Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine[1]

   Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost/asp5

   info: Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine[2]

   Request finished in 0ms 404

Why IIS not redirect http://localhost/asp5 to http://localhost:29715 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *Startup.cs* replace Configure(..) method with

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.Map("/asp5", (app1) => this.Configure1(app1, env, loggerFactory));
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure1(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    //OLD CODE
```

"**/asp5**" is name of Virtual app

Answer (score 0):

Check for two things:

1. Right-click on you Site in IIS and select "Edit Bindings...". In the opened window check if you have http binding on 29715
2. If bindings are correct, please open in a text editor your web.config on the server and check for httpRedirect tag

Comment: I dont need bind to 29715. IIS bind to 80. ASP5 start as separate web server with random port and I want transparent redirect http://localhost/asp5 to http://localhost:29715